# Jquery Modal or Rokbox binding with link

Tags: php, jquery, joomla, modal-dialog, mootools

Hi i have a simple code in a script to call for a new window with the links inside

To Open link in simple we can use :

```
jQuery('#documentViewer').bind('onExternalLinkClicked',function(e,link){
    window.open(link,'_flexpaper_exturl');
});
```

then i added this for the core joomla modal

To Open link in Joomla Modal bow we use :SqueezeBox.open(link, {handler: 'iframe'});

Please tell them how can we use rokbox or any other popup modal to open any link and bind it with #documentviewer?

this is the rokbox documentation

http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokbox#documentation

i cannot see a way to write direct execution event?

anyhelp will be appreciated

Comment: Please clearify: Do you want to use Rokbox and/or SqeezeBox? Do you want all links inside `#documentviewer` to open in a modal?

Comment: Where is `onExternalLinkClicked` defined?

Comment: Hello Sergio,
      I want to use rokbox. 

yes all links

but i dont have particular "<a >" from which we can define '<a href="http://www.anydomain.com" data-rokbox="">'. i have only a link which i want to open in rokbox popup. 
     "onExternalLinkClicked" defined in js from where i can open sqeezebox as i know SqueezeBox.open event but like this rokbox does not provide me DIRECT OPEN LINK event. as rokbox count all "<a >" whne window load and when you click on ant "<a>" popup opens.

http://devaldi.com/zine/js/flexpaper_handlers.js?r=131128

Comment: Did you try `$$('#documentViewer a').setProperty('data-rokbox', '');` ?